# Check validity of Azure Storage connection string before launching application

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-sql-database

I have a web application where "Azure Storage connection string" is passed as an environment variable in docker-compose file.

The problem is that Azure Storage is only related with a few features of the app, and if invalid connection string was passed, we won't noticed it until relevant functions failed in production.

I have tried `entrypoint.sh` for the app container. It seems to be a great place to check environment variables. But I cannot find a solution to validate "Azure Storage connection string" in this script.

Is it possible to validate "Azure Storage connection string" before making the app up & running?